# Microsoft Certificate Store

Tags: security, cryptography

I know that Microsoft Certificate store contains certificates with their corresponding private key.
Now when using Microsoft certificate store, do we have to create it ? If yes then how ? or we get it by default with windows, then where it is located in windows 7 ?
If possible, please give an example of using MS certificate Store to display all its contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to manage certs in Windows, type certmgr.msc into search and it will bring up the manager utility.

Answer (score 0):

It is default snap-in. Click on Start Ord, type certmgr.msc. If you need a cert it will import here automatically when cert is activated. This can happen a few ways, installing an application, logon script if in domain, etc. The certification is made by the developers when creating an application or portal.